# How do I paint with QPainter?

Tags: c++, qt

I have started learning Qt recently. 
I did not get quite clear how can I paint using `QPainter` class. Let`s say I want just to place a few points in the window:

```
class PointDrawer: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QPainter p;
public:
    PointDrawer(QWidget* obj=0): QWidget(obj), p(this) {}
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) {
        p.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 3));
        int n = 8;
        while(...) {
            qreal fAngle = 2 * 3.14 * i / n;
            qreal x = 50 + cos(fAngle) * 40;
            qreal y = 50 + sin(fAngle) * 40;
            p.drawPoint(QPointF(x, y));
                        i++;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    PointDrawer drawer;

    drawer.resize(200, 200);
    drawer.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

And after that, I got nothing!
Can you please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: and what if I don`t want to react on paintEvent? for example, if I press some button, I want to paint something. how can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is your `QPainter` initialization.

You could just create the `QPainter` like in hydroes' answer, it would look like this then:

```
class PointDrawer: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PointDrawer(QWidget* obj=0): QWidget(obj) {}
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) {
        QPainter p(this);
        p.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 3));
        int n = 8;
        while(...) {
                qreal fAngle = 2 * 3.14 * i / n;
                qreal x = 50 + cos(fAngle) * 40;
                qreal y = 50 + sin(fAngle) * 40;
                p.drawPoint(QPointF(x, y));
                        i++;
        }
    }
}
```

It could also use something like this, but I don't really recommend it (I just prefer the other solution):

```
class PointDrawer: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QPainter p;
public:
    PointDrawer(QWidget* obj=0): QWidget(obj) {}
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) {
        p.begin(this);
        p.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 3));
        int n = 8;
        while(...) {
                qreal fAngle = 2 * 3.14 * i / n;
                qreal x = 50 + cos(fAngle) * 40;
                qreal y = 50 + sin(fAngle) * 40;
                p.drawPoint(QPointF(x, y));
                        i++;
        }
        p.end();
    }
}
```

The `QPainter::begin(this)` and `QPainter::end()` calls are essential in the second example. In the first example, you can think of `QPainter::begin(this)` being called in the constructor and `QPainter::end()` in the destructor

For the reason, I'm guessing:
As `QPaintDevice`s are usually double buffered in QT4, `QPainter::end()` might be where the image is transferred to the graphic memory.

Answer (score 8):

```
void SimpleExampleWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
     QPainter painter(this);
     painter.setPen(Qt::blue);
     painter.setFont(QFont("Arial", 30));
     painter.drawText(rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Qt");
}
```

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.4/qpainter.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the painter with the widget you want to paint on.
Usually this is done using the constructor which takes a `QPaintDevice` but you can also do it by calling `begin()`.